# How to stop/pause MediaElementSource (web audio api)

Tags: angularjs, web-audio-api

I'm using Web Audio API to do a simple streaming audio using this function:
        function MyAudio(url){
            var song = new Audio();
            song.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            song.src = url;

```
        this.source = context.createMediaElementSource(song);
        this.source.connect(context.destination);
    }

    MyAudio.prototype.play = function(){
        this.source.mediaElement.play();
    };

    return MyAudio;
});
```

([more context here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669381/use-external-class-in-angularjs-controller))

But I can't figure out how to pause or stop it. I saw other questions here but they use noteOn/noteOff and that doesn't work in my case.

I have tried without success things like:

```
 MyAudio.prototype.stop = function(){
    this.source.mediaElement.noteOff();
}; 

 MyAudio.prototype.stop = function(){
    this.source.mediaElement.Stop();
}; 

 MyAudio.prototype.stop = function(){
    this.source.stop(0);
};
```

No luck.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14697336/3279156

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
MyAudio.prototype.stop = function(){
    this.source.mediaElement.pause();
    // To restart to the beginning on next play, not just resume
    this.source.mediaElement.currentTime = 0;
};
```